# QGraphicsItem validating a position change

Tags: qt

I have a custom QGraphicsItem implementation.  I need to be able to limit where the item can be moved - i,e. restrict it to a certain area.  When I checked the Qt documentation  this is what it suggested:

```
QVariant Component::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
 {
     if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene()) {
         // value is the new position.
         QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
         QRectF rect = scene()->sceneRect();
         if (!rect.contains(newPos)) {
             // Keep the item inside the scene rect.
             newPos.setX(qMin(rect.right(), qMax(newPos.x(), rect.left())));
             newPos.setY(qMin(rect.bottom(), qMax(newPos.y(), rect.top())));
             return newPos;
         }
     }
     return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
 }
```

So basically, check the position passed to itemChange, and if you don't like it, change it and return the new value.

Seems simple enough, except it doesn't actually work.  When I checked the call stack I see that itemChange is being called from QGraphicsItem::setPos, but it doesn't even look at the return value.  So there is no purpose to me returning a changed position, no one is looking at it.  See code from QGraphicsItem.cpp

```
// Notify the item that the position is changing.
    const QVariant newPosVariant(itemChange(ItemPositionChange, qVariantFromValue<QPointF>(pos)));
    QPointF newPos = newPosVariant.toPointF();
    if (newPos == d_ptr->pos)
        return;

    // Update and repositition.
    d_ptr->setPosHelper(newPos);

    // Send post-notification.
    itemChange(QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionHasChanged, newPosVariant);
    d_ptr->sendScenePosChange();
```

Any suggestions?  I was hoping to avoid re-implementing the whole click and drag behavior myself using mouse-down mouse-move etc..., but I suppose I will have to if I can't find a better idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't actually try it but it looks to me it is checking the return position. The returned restricted position is used in the constructor of `newPosVariant` to converted to `newPos`. It's then used to set the position of the item if it's different from the current one.

Comment: Ah!  I see my problem.  In my actual code, I was checking ItemPositionHasChanged instead of ItemPositionChange.  Which means all my position checking was happening in the wrong call to itemChange - the one that doesn't check the return type.  Thanks for making me look again at what I was doing.  That was silly of me.